How to preset a column to calculate a future date based on another column in Excel
Can someone help me with the formula to create a VBA or if there is another way to set it up so when a date is entered in Column E by someone on my worksheet it auto populates a future date (+10 business days) in Column I and (+12 business days) in Column L. Thank you!

For +10 Future Business Dates =WORKDAY(E1,SEQUENCE(10,,0)) or for +12 =WORKDAY(E1,SEQUENCE(12,,0))? This includes the date in E1, if the E1 is not needed then remove 0 from SEQUENCE() function

Try using WORKDAY() function:
• For +10 Future Business Dates
=WORKDAY(E1,SEQUENCE(10,,0))


• For +12 Future Business Dates
=WORKDAY(E1,SEQUENCE(12,,0)) 


This includes the date in E1, if the E1 is not needed then remove 0 from SEQUENCE() function, so it will be like
=WORKDAY(E1,SEQUENCE(10))


